# Interface interaction problem, parent-child widget interaction

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem. I haven’t thought of a perfect solution for a long time, so I ask for help.

I have an interface like this, I have already implemented the interface.

The middle part is the body of Scaffold, the bottom of PageView. is the bottomAppBar of Scaffold. The current confusion is that the page of pageview interacts with bottomAppBar, realize enable/disable of next/previour, and can click the click event at the bottom.

[image: Achieved effect]

I am trying to make child's state inherit an abstract class PracticeState

```
abstract class PracticeState {
  Duration get pageDuration;

  bool get haveNext;

  bool get havePrevious;

  VoidCallback get onPreviousClick;

  VoidCallback get onNextClick;

  VoidCallback get answerSheetClick;
}
```

When I extract AnswerModeState() as a variable, I throw an error when pageview switches page.

```
class AnswerMode extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback notifyParent;

  AnswerModeState practiceState = AnswerModeState();

  AnswerMode({
    Key key,
    @required this.notifyParent,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnswerMode> createState() {
    return practiceState;
  }
}

class AnswerModeState extends State<AnswerMode> implements PracticeState {
   ......
}
```

Comment: ```class AnswerMode extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback notifyParent;

  AnswerMode({
    Key key,
    @required this.notifyParent,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnswerMode> createState() {
    return AnswerModeState();
  }
}

class AnswerModeState extends State<AnswerMode> implements PracticeState {
  ......
//todo implement method 
}```

Comment: When used  
```var practiceState = ((_pages[_current].key as GlobalKey).currentState
        as PracticeView.PracticeState);```  
``` bottomNavigationBar: PracticeView.BottomBar(
        previous: practiceState?.havePrevious ?? false,
        next: practiceState?.haveNext ?? false,
        onNextClick: practiceState?.onNextClick ?? null,
        onPreviousClick: practiceState?.onPreviousClick ?? null,
        answerSheetClick: practiceState?.answerSheetClick ?? null,
      )```